# Matter.js - Delta time very high when switching tabs, bodies fall out of bounds

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm using Matter.js for a personal project. I have a loop like this to update the engine everytime it loops:

```
let prevTime = Date.now();
function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  let time = Date.now();
  let deltaTime = time - prevTime;
  prevTime = Date.now();
  Matter.Engine.update(engine, deltaTime);
};
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

And it works really well for what I'm using it for, but there's one thing bothering me. When I switch tabs or minimize my browser, the delta time is really high and the bodies pass through the ground and fall off screen. I tried fixing it with this code:

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  prevTime = Date.now();
});
```

but it didn't really do anything. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: Not really a fix, but I would use the high-precision timestamp parameter to RAF, or at least `performance.now()`, not `Date.now()`. As a workaround, you could ignore the delta when calling `Matter.Engine.update()`

Comment: Hmm, I'd prefer to have a time delta. I'll use a threshold if I won't find a better solution.

Comment: You could constrain the delta to some reasonable value, say, 125.